# How can I allow creating content for anonymous/authenticated users without programming in orchard?

Tags: content-management-system, content-type, orchardcms

we couldn't grant the users this possibility without letting them access the admin panel and granting them the author permission.

What we want to achieve is just like any other CMS, create a content type, and let users create content based on that, but without accessing the administration panel.
we're not asking for a lot are we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orchard 1.5 will handle that scenario. In earlier versions it's not possible without building your own module.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and Wow,, I'm wondering how could such basic feature be delayed until now

Comment: If I had a penny for every time someone said "wow... I'm wondering how could such a basic feature as feature X be delayed until now" I'd be a rich man. The problem is that everybody has a different idea of what feature X is. So you have two choices: you can build everything and the kitchen sink (a.k.a. the Microsoft Office tactic), or you can build a modular system with a core that is little more than an extensibility engine, and let everybody build their feature X themselves.

Comment: yes dear,, but we're speaking of the "creating content" part for a 3 years old project

Comment: Well, there is always a good way to get the feature you want out of an open source project: do it yourself. If you're not ready to do that, I'm afraid you will have to do with what others decide to do or not to do. Also, 1.0 was released in January 2011, and the first 0.1 release in March 2010 so that's 1.5 to 2 years. You are exaggerating. Also, 2 years is a ridiculously short amount of time to build something like Orchard. Especially as open source with very limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

While browsing the Orchard Gallery today, I saw this module [uSubmit](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.uSubmit).

It sounds like it handles what you need:
"Requires Orchard 1.4. This module provides a ContentType called UserSubmission for allowing anonymous visitors to submit content to your site. The content items that they can create include a title, an image, a story, and optionally their name, email address and tags. The story is entered with a Markdown editor, allowing them to provide a limited amount of formatting. The user submissions are saved as draft content and have to be published by an Orchard user (like the admin) with permissions to publish."

Hope this helps.